# Textview apply width attribute to programmatically added font, android

Tags: android, textview, width

I have a textview and I am changing the font programmatically in the java file.  When I do this some of the text gets cut off.  "Password Recovery" goes to "Password Recov" for example.    I figured that the wrap_content attribute was being applied to the old font, so I changed the width attribute of the textview to fill_parent, instead of wrap_content, and that worked.  That fixes it only if the textview is on one line.  But I have at least one text view that goes to two lines with the new font, and even with fill_parent, as mentioned earlier, it will not go down a line.  So the line "Your password has been emailed to" gets cut to "Your password has been emailed" without the to at the end.

I want the actual width attribute of my textview to be applied to my new font.  How can I do this?

Here is how I am changing the typeface:

In my PassRec.java

```
 private void init() {
    /*
     * load the fonts that are going to be used with this view
     */
    Typeface museoSans700 = Typeface.createFromAsset(JOMAppActivity.instance.getAssets(), "fonts/MuseoSans_700.otf");

    /*
     * start assigning layout elements to local variables
     */
    this.passRecoveryTxtView = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.passRecovTxtView);
    this.emailedTxtView = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    this.emailTxtView = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.userEmailAddPRE);
    this.returnBtn = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.returnSignInBtn);

    /*
     * Assign the fonts for the login layout
     */
    this.passRecoveryTxtView.setTypeface(museoSans700);
    this.emailedTxtView.setTypeface(museoSans700);
    this.emailTxtView.setTypeface(museoSans700);
```

Comment: When are you changing the Typeface?

Comment: I'm changing my pass_rec.xml, in my PassRec.java.

Comment: **When** are you changing it? Is this in `onCreate()`? You can always try a `textView.requestLayout()` after changing the `Typeface` but it shouldn't be necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for your answers, I tried them both.  I ended up just adding some text (blah blah) at the end of my string, then changing the text programmatically to the original string.

Answer (score 1):

Go to your XML Layout file and add

> android:maxLines="2"

and if there is a min lines delete it

Answer (score 1):

You could try use invalidate() on your TextView.